# Formato de texto Powershell al enviarlo por correo

Tags: powershell

Soy muy novato en Powershell y estoy creando un script que me notifique por correo cuando se apague o se encienda mi servidor Windows 2012, en general ya lo tengo prácticamente acabado solamente que al enviarlo por correo me aparece el mensaje

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData

en los datos que necesito que muestre, os dejo mi código por si alguien me puede ayudar (el `$correo` y `$pass` no los muestro porque son mi cuenta de gmail directamente, lo demás está aquí):

```
$smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$contenido = Get-EventLog System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq "1074"} | ft Machinename, TimeWritten, UserName, EventID, Message -AutoSize -Wrap
$pc = Get-content env:computername
$mensaje = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$mensaje.From = "$correo" 
$mensaje.To.Add("$correo")
$mensaje.BodyEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$mensaje.SubjectEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$mensaje.IsBodyHTML = $true 
$mensaje.Subject = "INICIO SISTEMA"
$mensaje.Body = "<h2> Su sistema se inició recientemente </h2>
</br>
Hola, esto es un aviso de tu $pc
Motivo: $contenido
" 
$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$correo","$pass");
$smtp.Send($mensaje)
```

Comment: También me gustaría saber si alguien me puede explicar como enviar en el correo solo la primera fila de datos y no todo el conjunto, porque no soy capaz de hacerlo de ninguna de las maneras, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el envío del mail funciona correctamente, lo único que deberías cambiar es como recolectas la información del evento.

Entiendo que es informativo, por lo que seleccioné únicamente el mensaje del evento de la siguiente manera:

```
$contenido = (Get-EventLog System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq "1074"}).Message
```

De lo anterior, podrías generar varios "contenidos diferentes, según lo que quieras mostrar (como la fecha).

Y luego sí, en el body ya puedes invocar la variable:

```
$mensaje.Body = "<h2> Su sistema se inició recientemente </h2>
</br>
Hola, esto es un aviso de tu $pc
Motivo:
<i>$contenido</i>
"
```

(convertí el mensaje a cursiva)

La otra opción es recolectar todos los valores y armar una tabla HTML para incluirla en el body con toda la información que seleccionaste inicialmente:

```
$contenido = Get-EventLog System | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq "1074"} | ft Machinename, TimeWritten, UserName, EventID, Message | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Donde se agrega el comando ConvertTo-Html con el parámetro Fragment para generar la tabla.